# MongoDB nodejs driver - what are the rules/guidelines around quotes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

When using the nodejs driver you could have something like

```
aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match : {total : {$exists : false}}
      },
    ...
    ...
```

which is also valid if

```
aggregate(
    [
      {
        "$match" : {"total" : {"$exists" : false}}
      },
    ...
    ...
```

What are the rules around quoting/not-quoting field or operator names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query pipeline in `aggregate()` is parsed by `JSON` parser in [`mongo Shell`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). And `JSON` does require quotes around object keys, JavaScript doesn't either.

The [query condition](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/query/) for an equality match on a field has the following form:

```
 { <field1>: <value1>, <field2>: <value2>, ... }
```

> If the `<field>` is a top-level field and not a field in an embedded document or an array, you can either **enclose the field name in quotes** or **omit the quotes**.